# Opening an accordion when clicking the first item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><b>My Title</b>:</li>
    <li class="subtitle">Subtitle 1</li>
    <li class="subtitle">Subtitle 2</li>
    <li class="subtitle">Subtitle 3</li>
</ul>
```

Where the class "subtitle" is display:none'ed by default. When I click on the first element in the list "**My Title**" I want the others to slide open (and then up when clicked again). Is there a way I can do this? JS or jQuery will do

Fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/at5gegme/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   var $nxt = $(this).next('.subtitle');
   $('.subtitle').not($nxt).slideUp('slow');
   $nxt.slideDown('slow');
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/at5gegme/15/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, this makes each subtitle slide down itself. I want all of the content under the main title to slide down as one

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/at5gegme/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and code like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#title").click(function(){
     $(".subtitle").slideDown();
     });

     $(".subtitle").click(function(){
     $(".subtitle").slideUp();
   });
  });
```

and customize according to your need